# Casting datetime64 to different time unit

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, datetime64

Suppose `T` is `numpy.datetime64` in units of ms. Is there a less obscure way to convert the units than this?

```
T1 = np.array( [T], dtype = 'datetime64[ns]' )[0]
```

I'm prefer something more guessable, and, for that matter, readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> x = numpy.datetime64('2005-02-25T03:30Z', 'ms')
>>> x
numpy.datetime64('2005-02-24T22:30:00.000-0500')
>>> numpy.datetime64(x, 'ns')
numpy.datetime64('2005-02-24T22:30:00.000000000-0500')
```